# Parsing a string with nested brackets

Tags: regex, parsing, nested, brackets

I'm writing a application to parse some commands. Commands are given in the form:

A { B }

I just want A and B. A is optional but that's easy enough to handle. The problem I'm having is that both A and B can contain almost any character including whitespace and '{' and '}'. The brackets need not be balanced, either. Is this possible to parse with a regex? If not, what is the simplest thing that you think could be done?

For example, given:

"parsme { foo { "hello" } { "goodbye" } {{{ } { bar { "up" } { "down" } }"

Then:

A = "parseme { foo { "hello" } { "goodbye" } {{{ }" and B = "bar { "up" } { "down" }"

Comment: The whitespace and other characters are less of a concern, but if you say the brackets need not be balanced, how would you ever know where B starts?

Comment: I can't comprehend how anyone is meant to distinguish B from A!

Comment: Sorry, I should have said the brackets in A need not be balanced.

Comment: You can use Balancing groups in .NET like described here:
http://www.marcomilani.it/2012/07/english-nested-strings-with-regular-expressions-similar-to-recursive-regex.html?lang=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a regular expression to parse anything that requires arbitrary nesting like parenthesis (this is a well established limitation of regular expressions, a little googling here will help you).

You will need to use a context-free grammar for this using a tool like Antlr.

Comment: +1. Well, you [**can** use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/1191425) (Perl) regular expressions to parse nested structures. Whether you want to or not is up to *you*...

Comment: @Li-aungYip: careful, that could scare some people away from programming for life!

Comment: @Len: In this particular case, that was the effect tchrist was going for. ;) Not every string processing problem admits a regex-based solution, and even for the ones that do admit regex solutions, sometimes you're better off with something else anyway.

Comment: Francis in .NET exist "Balancing groups"