# how to get nested values inside braces

Tags: php, regex

How to use php to get inside nested braces?

example:

```
{{ text1 {{text2 text3 {{text4}} text5}} }}
```

should output

```
1- text1 {{text2 text3 {{text4}} text5}}
2- text2 text3 {{text4}} text5
3- text4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer i was looking for and put this here so everyone could use it. Its very simple indeed, in one line only:

```
  $text1=preg_replace("/\{\{(([^{}]*|(?R))*)\}\}/",'',$text1);
```

It will search and replace all {{text}} with whatever you want. You can also use the preg_match_all to get all of them in an array.

Answer (score 5):

This requires keeping track of the number of brackets and cannot be done using regex. You will have to create your own parser logic for this. [Regex is not a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not), sorry.

[Here is another similar question with the same response as mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423970/parsing-a-string-with-nested-brackets)

[And here is a SO about building parses (in Java, but it should translate well enough)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251781/java-method-for-parsing-nested-expressions)

Comment: Yes it can be done using regex - you just aren't trying hard enough!

Comment: @ridgerunner True regular expressions cannot do this. Maybe some engines can implement logic, but the base regex cannot. Until all engines can handle this, then I stand by my answer. Also, you do have to begin to weigh the simplicity and readability...

Comment: When you say "TRUE" regular expressions, which specific engine are you talking about? Ruby, Java, JavaScript, Perl, PHP, C#, Python or even grep? Regular expressions have not been REGULAR for a long time. See tchrist's excellent response to a similar claim: [Do NOT try parsing with regular expressions](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html#comment_40).

Comment: sorry, i don't understand, why people vote up this question. can anybody explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

PCRE, like Perl can match nested structures to any arbitrary depth (limited only by memory - see below). Here is a tested script:

### Regex to match nested brackets

```php
<?php // test.php Rev:20120702_1100

$re_nested_double_bracket ='% # Rev:20120702_1100
    # Match {{...{{...}}...}} structure with arbitrary nesting.
    \{\{                      # Opening literal double bracket.
    (                         # $1: Contents of double brackets.
      (?:                     # Group for contents alternatives.
        [^{}]++               # Either one or more non-brackets,
      | (?R)                  # or a nested bracket pair,
      | \{                    # or the start of opening bracket
        (?!\{)                # (if not a complete open bracket),
      | \}                    # or the start of closing bracket.
        (?!\})                # (if not a complete close bracket).
      )*                      # Zero or more contents alternatives.
    )                         # End $1: Contents of double brackets.
    \}\}                      # Closing literal double bracket.
    %x';

$results = array(); // Global array to receive results.

// Recursively called callback routine adds to $results array.
function _bracket_contents_callback($matches) {
    global $results, $re_nested_double_bracket;
    $results[] = $matches[1];
    preg_replace_callback($re_nested_double_bracket,
        '_bracket_contents_callback', $matches[1]);
    return $matches[0]; // Don't modify string.
}

$input = file_get_contents('testdata.txt');
preg_replace_callback($re_nested_double_bracket,
    '_bracket_contents_callback', $input);

$count = count($results);
printf("There were %d matches found.\n", $count);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    printf("  Match[%d]: %s\n", $i + 1, $results[$i]);
}
?>
```

When run against the test data in the original post, here is what the regex matches:

### Example Output:

`There were 3 matches found.`
`Match[1]:  text1 {{text2 text3 {{text4}} text5}}`
`Match[2]: text2 text3 {{text4}} text5`
`Match[3]: text4`

Note that this regex matches the *outermost* set of possibly nested brackets and captures into group `$1` the contents between the brackets. The script makes use of the `preg_replace_callback()` function to recursively match and add nested bracket contents to the results array.

**"Arbitrary depth"** Note that this solution matches nested brackets to any "arbitrary depth", but is always limited by system memory, executable stack size and the PHP `pcre.backtrack_limit`, `pcre.recursion_limit` and `memory_limit` configuration variables. Note that it is certainly possible for this regex solution to fail if the subject string is too large and/or the nesting too deep for a given host system. It is even possible for the PHP/PCRE library to cause the running executable to generate a stack overflow, segmentation-fault and program crash! See my answer to a related question for an in-depth discussion on how and why this can occur (and how to avoid it and gracefully handle errors of this sort):
[RegExp in preg_match function returning browser error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7627962/433790) and
[PHP regex: is there anything wrong with this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5527831/433790).

Note: This question (and my answer) are almost the same as: [Parsing proprietary tag syntax with regex - how to detect nested tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11281587/433790), but in this answer, a fuller solution is presented which recursively matches and stores all nested bracket contents.